# How can I properties to the return of NextAuth authorize function?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am fairly new to NextAuth, I tried using it following the documentation to authenticate using credentials(username, password). Like this:

```
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: 'Username',
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'johndoe',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Password',
          type: 'password',
          placeholder: '••••••••',
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const res = await axios.post('/auth/login/', credentials);
        const user = res.data as User; // Explicitly cast the response data to the User type

        if (res.status === 201 && user) {
          return user;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any; user: User }) {
      if (user) {
        if (user.accessToken) {
          token = {
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            accessToken: user.accessToken,
          };
        }
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any; token: User }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.id = token.id;
      session.username = token.username;

      return session;
    },
  },
};
```

In both callbacks(jwt, session), I am getting these typescript errors:

```
Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'User | AdapterUser'.
  Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)

Property 'username' does not exist on type 'User | AdapterUser'.
  Property 'username' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)

Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'Session'.ts(2339)

Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Session'.ts(2339)

Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Session'.ts(2339)
```

How can I deal with these type of errors?

I have tried to extend the interface User but the issue remains